# Display a json without only one field

Tags: python, json

how can i display this json private of the field user

I don't want to do this:

```
result = [x['date']['nom']['count'] for x in hits] 

{'date': '04-04-2019', 'nom': 'Iphone', 'count': 0, 'users': [1]}
```

Comment: "i dont want to do this: result = [x['date']['nom']['count'] for x in hits]" indeed you can't, because it's not a nested dictionary so multiple keys would not be valid.

Comment: What is it you want to display? Can you show a clear example of what you expect as your output (or as the content of the `result` variable)?

Comment: You do not have to go left-to-right through a dictionary to get the result. `result = x['count']` will take you straight to the value, ignore the other keys in the dictionary. If you have multiple dictionaries in a list: `result = [x['count'] for x in hits]`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want is:

```
result = [{k:v for k, v in entry.items() if k != 'users'} for entry in hits]
```

A more general case is probably:

```
def filter_dict(d: Mapping[String, Any],
                blacklist: Optional[List[String]]=None) -> Mapping[String, Any]:
    if blacklist is None:
        return d

    return {k:v for k, v in d.items() if k not in blacklist}

result = [filter_dict(entry, blacklist=['users']) for entry in hits]
```

Comment: I think they just think they need to traverse left-to-right through all the keys to get to the one they want in a flat dictionary

Comment: @roganjosh I don't think so. "Display a json without only one field" translates to "Ignore one key in this dictionary" to me. I think "display this json private of the field user" means that `users` shouldn't be publicly accessible, and the attempt is pseudocode to mean "include these keys and only these keys"

Comment: Look at the attempt though in relation to the subsequent dict. It wasn't clear to me when editing whether it was starting data or the result of their multiple keys, but the order matches up

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution:

```
def removekey(d, key):
    r = dict(d)
    del r[key]
    return r


texte = [removekey(x['_source'], 'users') for x in hits]
```

Comment: Please make sure you format code as code. Paste code as a block and highlight it all; you can then either use ctrl + k or click the `{}` button in the editor. That said, this couldn't possibly work with the data in your question because `'_source'` doesn't even exist as a key. This is indicative of you not providing a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: thx for the advices, x['_source'] is header of the json, i can access to the json by it.But you are right it is not mentionned anywhere